# How do I get the time a queried CIM Indication Event was created and the current time when it is handled?

Tags: windows, powershell, events, event-handling

Context: `__InstanceCreationEvent` in Windows CIM Indication Event Engine

I am registered to receive an `__InstanceCreationEvent` (docs), and I am checking the `TimeGenerated` attribute ([PSEventArgs Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pseventargs?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0)).  This is my zero time. I would like to calculate the delta time since then.

This will be the time the event is handled by my code.

```
$event = Register-CimIndicationEvent -SourceIdentifier "Foo" -Query "$myQuery" -Action {

  $targetInstance = $eventArgs.NewEvent.TargetInstance
  $eventZeroDateTime = $eventArgs.TimeGenerated # ostensibly a DateTime object
  $eventZero = Get-Date ($eventZeroDateTime).ToUniversalTime() -UFormat %s
  $actionZero = Get-Date (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime() -UFormat %s

  $deltat = $actionZero - $eventZero

  Write-Verbose "Delta T: $deltat"
}
```

---

Solutions pursued:

1. ChatGPT: I've asked this thing, and it is routinely giving me a plausible, but variable, equation for computing the number of ticks since Jan 1, 1601 (ticks = 100 nanoseconds). This is an alright approach (although the equations are wrong), but the `TIME_CREATED` parameter of the [__InstanceCreationEvent class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/--instancecreationevent) is the only parameter in Tick time.  I don't need tick time right now, and I don't know how to access it other than by calling `$eventArgs.NewEvent.TIME_CREATED` (which is an undocumented method I suspect creates a new event right then and has nothing to do with the time the original event was created).  Either way, an answer that results in the tick time since the event creation would be the Y answer to the X question.
2. Perused the Microsoft documentation on the topic
3. Guess and check using the `Action` block